# Use iMac as a networked second display for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mac, miracast, airplay

I've spent an extensive amount of time researching and trying various solutions to use an iMac as a second networked display for Windows 10. Both systems are connected to the network via Ethernet on the same network (same VLAN). Solutions I've tried:

- [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com) as a Miracast receiver on the mac - Does not appear as an available screen from the Windows system (but Roku devices on my network do)
- [Reflector 3](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector) as a Miracast receiver on mac - Same failure as above
- AirServer as an Airplay server and [AirParrot 2](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) on Windows - Does not support extending display

The iMac is a 21.5-inch Late 2013 and based on the research I've done it will not support Target Display Mode from Windows -- but if anyone happens to have gotten this working from a Windows PC with HDMI or Micro DisplayPort to this model of Mac I'm all ears.

Can anyone confirm a working solution for this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Can VLC stream to the LAN? If so, watch the output in  Opera.